# No solution to "Bone Heat Weighting: failed to find solution for one or more bones" blender 2.8

Tags: mesh, armature, bones, parent

I have this issue but not found any solution working for me. I am new to blender and modelling, and I am aware that my model is far from perfect. But my armature is quite simple. I have tried to clean the mesh, remove some wrong faces...but I still have the issue when parenting...Thank you for any idea !
[image]

Answer (score 0):

To be more specific, I have already tried a "remove double/merge by distance" on the mesh, and a scale

Found the solution: I fixed the nose vertices which was dirty and the parenting worked. Thank you for reading :)

Comment: And the mesh is made with only one part